# Como saber o motivo dos downvotes

Tags: debate, respostas, voto-contra

Ontem, [escrevi uma resposta que resolve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/462342/imprimir-v%C3%A1rios-n%C3%BAmeros-com-um-separador-entre-eles-mas-n%C3%A3o-colocar-o-separador/) o problema apresentado, explica o procedimento e dá uma dica de melhor prática.

Mesmo assim recebeu 3 downvotes e nenhum comentário de melhoria ou algo do tipo. Não concordo, mas aceito já que não foi somente 1 voto negativo isolado, portanto, deve ter algo em não-conformidade. Escrevo aqui para que me indicassem o que eu fiz de errado nela, pois não quero repetir o erro (grosseiro, tendo em vista a rápida rejeição pela comunidade).

De certo modo, todas as respostas até agora levam pelo mesmo caminho, mas só a minha foi "downvotada".

P.S. Dei voto a favor da resposta do @hkotsubo, pois é muito mais detalhada do que a minha. Só queria entender mesmo onde errei.

Comment: Não posso falar pelos votantes, mas já pela idéia de "economizar linha" (atrapalha legibilidade, não tem benefício técnico), diria que não é anormal negativo, e em seguida você faz um loop e ainda usa compreensão de lista, em vez de já imprimir no loop, também pode ser que os votantes levem em consideração (novamente, os motivos, ainda mais sendo pessoas diferentes, podem não ser esses - tou te dizendo o que vejo numa lida rápida na esperança de te apontar problemas). Lembrando ainda que downvote quase não tira reputação, e é só para"ordenação". Use como incentivo a tomar cuidado e melhorar.

Comment: De qualquer forma, esse post seu aqui do meta eu creio ser duplicata (a não ser que ponha a tag "pergunta-específica", não lembro se tem "resposta-especifica"). O bom de trazer pro meta é que dá visibilidade, aí pelo rumo que a resposta tomar dá uma noção melhor (aumentando o número de votos, seja pra que lado for), melhora a percepção da postagem e pode atrair comentários extra.

Comment: Eu náo posso afirmar que esse seja o motivo dos downvotes, só quem votou pode afirmar, mas eu não entendi porque você usou um for dentro de print, não seria mais fácil usar join()? Algo como `for n in range(1, 100):\nif n % 5 == 0:\nvalores.append(str(n))\nprint('|'.join(valores))` ... ou simplesmente no print com unpacking aplicar o if "dentro" do for? Porque me parece que 2 fors é totalmente dispensável, no segundo caso nem append é necessário (que foi o sugerido na resposta do @hkotsubo) ... acho q a questão não é se todas resps levam ao mesmo caminho, algo funcionar não significa que "ok"

Comment: Acho que fazer comentários de feedback ao dar o downvote é uma atitude que deveria ser mais estimulada. Fica muito mais difícil de melhorar se não lhe disserem onde você está errando. Isso vale também pra fechamentos de perguntas, apesar de ser exibido uma espécie de briefing do motivo do fechamento, ele fica muito genérico em algumas situações